# Spring Boot OAuth TokenStore is always empty

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth

I'm trying to implement an OAuth Authentication Server with Spring Boot OAuth package. I was following [this](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs) article, but instead of using JDBC TokenStore I only need InMemoryTokenStore and implicit grant for the start.

The application is secured with form login and I'm able to login, grant access and get redirected to with a short token to the redirect uri. But after that, the InMemoryTokenStore is empty. I tried debugging and it looks like the method storeAccessToken is never called.

My config file looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2ServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
                .inMemory()
                .withClient("tripapp")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit")
                .redirectUris("http://localhost:8080/redirect")
                .scopes("read")
                .authorities("USER")
                .autoApprove(false)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
}
```

Has anyone an idea, where the problem is?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this yet?